# How can remove the titlebar and remain the browser in fullscreen

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first app, the browser for android with this code already done, but needed to adapt to my necessity. I still do not know java, and the examples I find I can not make it work. 
I need help and reading.

How can remove the titlebar and remain the browser in fullscreen?
for later viewing and interacting with my application in jquery mobile

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);



        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tscolari.mobile_sample"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:name=".AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - in your layout, set the WebView to match_parent in both layout_width and layout_height
2 - in your code, add these lines:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Hiding Title bar of this activity screen
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

// Making this activity full screen
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in place of the existing

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

If your IDE is NOT SET to add the missing imports, just add the following line to your imports:

```
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Comment: WindowManager or Window cannot be resolved to a variable. for what I have to replace?

Comment: i hade to import android.view.Window; for getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); to works. I'm right in what I did?

Comment: Does it work? - Yes, I forgot it... I've set my IDE to automatically add the missing imports on save... ;) Sure, you got to add all the missing imports, I'm updating my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

update your manifeist like this :
only mentioning one thing:
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="tscolari.mobile_sample"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <activity android:name=".AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity"
                      android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: @user1691150 brother i have just given your answer okk.. Don`t show this type of behaviour

Comment: @Ravind Maurya: I think he really showed gratitude, not hirony.

Comment: My english is not good and sometimes Interpretation 
the other side can understand that I am aggressive, but it is not the case. I am very grateful for your help.